# Perl: break down a string, with some unique constraints

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl to feed data to an LCD display. The display is 8 characters wide. The strings of data to be displayed are always significantly longer than 8 characters. As such, I need to break the strings down into "frames" of 8 characters or less, and feed the "frames" to the display one at a time.

The display is not intelligent enough to do this on its own. The only convenience it offers is that strings of less than 8 characters are automatically centered on the display.

In the beginning, I simply sent the string 8 characters at a time - here goes 1-8, now 9-16, now 17-24, etc. But that wasn't especially nice-looking. I'd like to do something better, but I'm not sure how best to approach it.

These are the constraints I'd like to implement:

- Fit as many words into a "frame" as possible
- No starting/trailing space(s) in a "frame"
- Symbol (ie. hyphen, ampersand, etc) with a space on both sides qualifies as a word
- If a word is longer than 8 characters, simulate per-character scrolling
- Break words longer than 8 characters at a slash or hyphen

Some hypothetical input strings, and desired output for each...

```
Electric Light Orchestra - Sweet Talkin' Woman

Electric
Light
Orchestr
rchestra
- Sweet
Talkin'
Woman


Quarterflash - Harden My Heart

Quarterf
uarterfl
arterfla
rterflas
terflash
- Harden
My Heart


Steve Miller Band - Fly Like An Eagle

Steve
Miller
Band -
Fly Like
An Eagle


Hall & Oates - Did It In A Minute

Hall &
Oates -
Did It
In A
Minute


Bachman-Turner Overdrive - You Ain't Seen Nothing Yet

Bachman-
Turner
Overdriv
verdrive
- You
Ain't
Seen
Nothing
Yet
```

Being a relative Perl newbie, I'm trying to picture how would be best to handle this. Certainly I could `split` the string into an array of individual words. From there, perhaps I could loop through the array, counting the letters in each subsequent word to build the 8-character "frames". Upon encountering a word longer than 8 characters, I could then repetitively call `substr` on that word (with offset +1 each time), creating the illusion of scrolling.

Is this a reasonable way to accomplish my goal? Or am I reinventing the wheel here? How would you do it?

Comment: Your algorithm seems quite sounds. Challenges you'll face are probably around short words and non-word characters like the `-` and `&`. But shouldn't be too hard to implement that. I suggest you write a couple of unit tests, and produce arrays of strings as your frames, then test against that.

Comment: Why not just scroll the whole string? I feel pretty sure that is the solution I would pick, and it would save you from inventing the logic around length calculations, just `use Time::HiRes qw(usleep); while ($running) { print substr $str, 0, 8; $str =~ s/^(.)(.+)/$2$1/; usleep 100_000; }`. Simple and effective, up and running in 2 mins. You could probably also tweak substr to do the character shuffling, it is quite a powerful tool if you read the documentation, but this does the trick.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does your setup work? What Perl code do you use to manipulate the display?

Answer (score 3):

The base question is to find all consecutive overlapping N-long substrings in a compact way.

Here it is in one pass with a regex, and see the end for doing it using `substr`.

```
my $str = join '', "a".."k";    # 'Quarterflash';
    
my @eights = $str =~ /(?=(.{8}))/g;
```

This uses a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) which also captures, and in this way the regex crawls up the string character by character, capturing the "next" eight each time.

Once we are at it, here is also a basic solution for the problem. Add words to a buffer until it would exceed 8 characters, at which point it is added to an array of display-ready strings and cleared.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = shift // "Quarterflash - Harden My Heart";

my @words = split ' ', $str;  

my @to_display; 
my $buf = ''; 

foreach my $w (@words) {      
    if (length $w > 8) {  
        # Now have to process the buffer first then deal with this long word
        push @to_display, $buf;
        $buf = '';
        push @to_display, $w =~ /(?=(.{8}))/g;
    }   
    elsif ( length($buf) + 1 + length($w) > 8 ) { 
        push @to_display, $buf;
        $buf = $w; 
    }
    elsif (length $buf != 0) { $buf .= ' ' . $w }
    else                     { $buf  = $w       }   
}    
push @to_display, $buf if $buf;
    
say for @to_display;
```

This is clearly missing some special/edge cases, in particular those involving non-word characters and hyphenated words, but that shouldn't be too difficult to add.<sup>†</sup>

Here is a way to get all consecutive 8-long substrings using `substr`

```
my @to_display = map { substr $str, $_, 8 } 0..length($str)-8;
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Example, break a word with hyphen/slash when it has no spaces around it (per question)

```
my @parts = split m{\s+|(?<=\S)[-/](?=\S)}, $w;
```

The hyphen/slash is discarded as this stands; that can be changed by capturing the pattern as well and then filtering out elements with only spaces

```
my @parts = grep { /\S/ } split m{( \s+ | (?<=\S) [-/] (?=\S) )}x, $w;
```

These haven't been tested beyond just barely.  Can fit in the `if (length $w > 8)` branch.

---

*The initial take-- The regex was originally written with a two-part pattern.  Keeping it here for record and as an example of use of pair-handling functions from `List::Util`*

The regex below matches and captures a character, followed by a lookahead for the next seven, which it also captures. This way the engine captures 1 and 7-long substrings as it moves along char by char. Then the consecutive pairs from the returned list are joined

```
my $str = join '', "a".."k";    # 'Quarterflash';

use List::Util qw(pairmap);

my @eights = pairmap { $a . $b } $str =~ /(. (?=(.{7})) )/gx;

# or 
# use List::Util qw(pairs);
# my @eights = map { join '', @$_ } pairs $str =~ /(.(?=(.{7})))/g;
```